# multipart/form-data without a boundary

Tags: http, multipartform-data, boundary

Is a multipart/form-data request valid without a boundary? According to the specification when there are more than 1 parts then boundary is used to separate them(and this boundary should not be part of the body).  I have a request where there is a single body as a raw content or a file and in the content-type we pass "multipart/form-data" . Is this kind of request actually valid?

Answer (score 10):

I think `multipart/form-data` request without a boundary is **invalid**.

According to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), request with only 1 part is still valid `multipart` MIME type and should follow `multipart` MIME rules:

> MIME provides for a number of "multipart" types -- encapsulations of **one or more representations** within a single message body.  All multipart types share a common syntax ... **and include a boundary parameter** as part of the media type value.

According to [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1), "boundary" is required and mandatory:

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities **requires** one parameter, "boundary".
>
> ...
>
> The only **mandatory** global parameter for the "multipart" media type is the boundary parameter

Comment: FYI: This is also conclusive with the [`multipart/form-data` media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/multipart/form-data).